# Selecting the first and the last word from a 3 word long string in PLSQL

Tags: string, plsql, substr

For example I have names like these:

```
John Lucas Smith    
Kevin Thomas Bacon
```

I need to do it with regexp_substr, or replace or something like that.

and what I want to get is:

```
John Smith    
Kevin Bacon
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try to use f_convert function to split your string into array, it works for space and comma separated string both

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'John Lucas Smith'   from dual union
  3     select 'Kevin Thomas Bacon' from dual union
  4     select 'Little Foot'        from dual
  5    )
  6  select regexp_substr(col, '^\w+') ||' '||
  7         regexp_substr(col, '\w+$') first_and_last
  8  from test;

FIRST_AND_LAST
-------------------------------------
John Smith
Kevin Bacon
Little Foot

SQL>
```